# Nuxt 3 SSR deploy - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED/Canceled

Tags: vuejs3, web-deployment, server-side-rendering, vite, nuxtjs3

I deployed my Nuxt 3 project on server(IIS) using these commands:

```
npm i
npm run build
npm run preview (in .output folder)
```

But when I try to open the website I get this error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Page structure and styles loads fine but images and js files get this error!

Comment: Did you fine solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @july77 sorry for very late response, but it was something related to windows server and dev-ops coworker solved it. I personally don't know what he did back then.